# One user of published app getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, google-play

I have a published app (in the Play Store) and it's working normally. But I've seen that ONE user is getting the android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException.

http://crashes.to/s/0d480232739

The stacktrace tells me that a drawable resource wasn't found. But it makes no sense, since this is a normal drawable that is included in the app. And moreover, these exceptions doesn't happen with anyone else.

Have you ever seen something like that? Is there any chance that the installation of this user was corrupted in some way?

Comment: Your user may have an old api version, then "mdpi" folder is call instead of "hdpi", did you copy your drawables into all res folders ?

Comment: This drawable is actually a layer-list drawable that references other image drawables. So, it's inside /res/drawable.

Comment: Put a try catch to avoid crash, or set an "ImageErrorResource"... Good luck

Comment: Actually, your problem is from an image inside of the `LayerListDrawable`: `Binary XML file line #7: <bitmap> requires a valid src attribute`

Comment: Thank you, @CommonsWare. I didn't notice it. Anyway, I checked the drawable's XML and it has a valid src attribute. It's very strange because this is the unique user who have this bug.

Answer (score 1):

The activity could happen to be killed by system after the unique user hid it into background, and then restarted by activity manager who is always monitoring all activities. Please check your code in this case